# Google Cloud Platform project is being suspended, I tried to submit an appeal but not working

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, youtube-api

About 2 weeks ago, I found that my GCP project (using YouTube API) is being suspended for violating Google Cloud Platform Terms of Service or Acceptable Use Policy by circumventing quota restrictions via multiple projects acting as one.

I've deleted all other projects and submitted an appeal for 12 days ago, but the main project is still locked and no response from Google support.

I just keep receiving 2 emails from Google system when I submit an appeal again:

> Thank you for your follow up. A member of our team will review the appeal for your Google Cloud Project and get back to you within two business days.

and

> We have recently detected your Google Cloud / APIs Projects have been circumventing our quota restrictions via multiple projects acting as one and appears to be violating YouTube API Terms of Service (III.D.1.c).
>
> You can fix the problem by taking the following steps:
>
> 1. Consolidate your projects behind one single project ID and delete the remaining projects
> 2. Once you've completed step 1, sign in to your remaining active project and submit an appeal

How can I solve the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: That is in YouTube/Google's hands - not much you can do - except maybe create a whole new project...

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait and check constantly your email for any requested information from the Google side. Try to be as detailed as you can and try to provide as much evidence as possible. This process sometimes can take some time to be reviewed. If you have submitted an appeal, you just can wait and keep monitoring your mail. On the other hand, you can create a new Project.